# How to save/update a HTML page locally using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

So, I want to code a simple HTML page as an overlay for OBS and inside the page there is an input field which is editing content to an HTML element.
I want to be able to save or update the entire page without right click Save As.
Upon refreshing the page the edited content from the input field does not "stick"...
Is it possible to add a piece of javascript and a button to save/update the entire HTML page with edited content?

This is the [code I am using right now](https://jsfiddle.net/cle_dan/ev6L8z0t/3/)
Input field shows the typed text. Upon refreshing the page, typed content is gone. I need to update the page so the typed content is still visible upon refreshing the HTML document.

I'm not a programmer, nor do I have extensive skills so please do not reply to my question with other questions using technical terms. And please DO not post a links to other so called solutions because I've already tested 22 "solutions" and nothing worked.

Thank you.

```
    document.getElementById("ChangeIt").addEventListener("keyup", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
    var elementValue = document.getElementById("ChangeIt").value;
    document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = elementValue;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p><i id="username"></i></p>
<p><input id="ChangeIt" name="ChangeIt" type="text" value="" class="username"></p>
<p>Type in the box above</p>
```

Comment: Is `localStorage` available to you?

Comment: Yes my browser is supporting localStoarage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your environment supports `localStorage`, then it should be pretty easy: any time an input changes, alter a `localStorage` value. Also, on pageload, go through `localStorage` and populate each `input`. For example:

```
<p><i id="username"></i></p>
<p><input id="ChangeIt" name="ChangeIt" type="text" value="" class="username"></p>
<p>Type in the box above</p>

<input id="ChangeIt2" type="text" value="" class="username" placeholder="some other input">
```

JS:

```
const savedText = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('savedText')) || {};
Object.entries(savedText).forEach(([id, val]) => {
  document.getElementById(id).value = val;
});
document.body.addEventListener('keyup', ({ target: { value, id } }) => {
  if (!id || !value) return;
  savedText[id] = value;
  localStorage.savedText = JSON.stringify(savedText);
})


document.getElementById("ChangeIt").addEventListener("keyup", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
  var elementValue = document.getElementById("ChangeIt").value;
    document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = elementValue;
}
myFunction();
```

I can't embed it as a stack snippet because stack snippets don't support `localStorage`.

https://jsfiddle.net/ev6L8z0t/4/

Note that this implementation requires that each element that gets its `value` saved have an `id`, but of course you can tweak that to suit your needs.